# Pressing a button with Enter key

Tags: javascript, extjs

**ExtJS 5.1**

I have a form and a button that calls other view when you click.

How can i submit the form with Enter key?

**My Button Code:**

```
{
 xtype: 'button',
 reference: 'btnLogin',
 text: 'Login',
 listeners: {
           click: 'onBtnLoginClick'
           }
 }
```

**Click Button Event (if necessary)**

```
this.getView().destroy();

var mainPageView = Ext.create('HomePage.view.mainPage',{title : ''});

var wind=Ext.create('Ext.Window',{
    itemId:'mainPage',
    items:[mainPageView],
    title:'HI',
    modal:false,
    closeAction:'destroy',
    resizable:false,
    closable: false,
    listeners:{
        'close':function(win){
            mainPageView.close();
        }
    }
});
wind.show();
```

Comment: Can you post the complete form?

Comment: just focus on the button

Answer (score 0):

you can doing following code. from which field you want to work press `Enter` button.

```
specialkey  : function (me, el) {

    if (el.getKey() == Ext.EventObject.ENTER){
        //TODO YOUR CODE Work on Press enter

    }
}
```